# Selenium: getPageSource() returns previous pages' source

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm logging into the page using this function:

```
public static void login() {
   driver.get(url);
   driver.findElement(By.name("username")).clear();
   driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("username- login");
   driver.findElement(By.name("password")).clear();
   driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("password");
   driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).click();
   driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

}

The login is successful and now i'd like to verify this by checking for certain elements on the landing page as follows:

```
public static void testLogin(WebDriver driver) {
   String pageSource = driver.getPageSource();
   //Assert.assertTrue("Login was not successful!", pageSource.contains("Welcome to the page!"));
   System.out.println(pageSource);
```

}

Everything works except for the fact that when i display the source code on the console, it is the source code of the login page (previous url) and hence the Assert returns false.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wait some time until new page opened:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);  
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[contains(.,'Welcome to the page!')]")));
```

This should allow you to wait until element from new page that contains text value `'Welcome to the page!'` present in `DOM`

Or You can wait until page title is changed:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("New page title"));
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be timing issue. Wait for some element on your new page to appear and than get page source.